# Getting rid of duplicate item_id but adding price to initial row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

version = MySQL 8.0

MRE:

```
create table test_table(
    item_id int,
    price decimal,
    transaction_time datetime
);

insert into test_table(item_id, price, transaction_time)
Values (1, 5500, "2020-01-01 00:11:11")
     , (1, 1000, "2020-01-07 01:11:11")
     , (3, 1100, "2020-01-06 18:10:10")
     , (3, 7700, "2020-01-03 18:10:10")
     , (4, 1900, "2020-01-02 12:00:11");
```

Using windowing function to get cumulative price for each item_id I run:

```
select *
     , sum(price) over(partition by item_id) as cum_fee
  from test_table;
```

which outputs:

```
  item_id   price    transaction_time     cum_fee
    1       5500    2020-01-01 00:11:11     6500
    1       1000    2020-01-07 01:11:11     6500
    3       1100    2020-01-06 18:10:10     8800
    3       7700    2020-01-03 18:10:10     8800
    4       1900    2020-01-02 12:00:11     1900
```

Now I want to get rid of duplicate item_id. The reason I added windowing function is I want to get rid of duplicate item_id but want to keep their cumulative price "cum_fee".

My initial attempt was groupby item_id at the end:

```
select *
     , sum(price) over(partition by item_id) as cum_fee
  from test_table
group by item_id;
```

this seems to groupby item_id first then runs windowing function outputting:

```
   item_id   price       transaction_time        cum_fee
      1       5500        2020-01-01 00:11:11       5500
      3       1100        2020-01-06 18:10:10       1100
      4       1900        2020-01-02 12:00:11       1900
```

I know people comparing groupby Vs. windowing function which probably means we use either one but not both? is it true?

is yes, what is an alternative method to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want aggregation.  Perhaps this?

```
select item_id, min(price), min(transaction_time), sum(price)
from test_table
group by item_id;
```

Window functions do not change the number of rows.  That is what `group by` does.

Comment: Yeah that's what I want to do. I must've been lost... or tried to over complicate a simple query. Thanks anyway.